# Vlc media player started stuttering during playback

Tags: vlc, horus

When I upgraded to `elementary OS 7 Horus`, the `Vlc media player` installed via `APT` started stuttering during playback. So when I pause and/or resume a video, the audio fades away for a bit of seconds (while video is playing) then it resumes back again.